# PHP+Xpath: remove first child?

Tags: php, xpath

I have a xpath expression that returns a list of urls that are in a table. I now need a way to remove the first tr, is this possible using one xpath expression? FYI the expression looks like this:

> form[@id='form1']/div[@id='cont']/div[@id='mycont']/div[@id='holder']/div[@id='resultslist']/div[2]/table//**tr**/td[2]/a/@href

The relevant tr is in bold. I'm coding in php which doesn't support xpath 2 afaik.

Comment: On a side note: doesn't your (DOM?)XPath version support `getElementById`? Problems with it were fixed in recent libxml2/php versions, and seaching relative to the node `resultslist` would be far more effective.

Comment: As far as i know, id() is not supported in the current default php lib.

Comment: Erm, yes, it is, and here ( PHP version 5.3.2, libxml2 2.7.7)  DOMDocument::getElementById works just fine & wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form[@id='form1']
 /div[@id='cont']
  /div[@id='mycont']
   /div[@id='holder']
    /div[@id='resultslist']
     /div[2]
      /table
       //tr[position() > 1]
        /td[2]/a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr[preceding-sibling::tr]`